Exceptions Caught by Gesture
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

class BottomNavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const BottomNavBar({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Ensure router is initialized

    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 47, 47, 47),
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(40.0)),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
            spreadRadius: 1,
            blurRadius: 10,
            offset: const Offset(0, -3),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 60.0,
          width: 345.0,
          child: BottomAppBar(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () {
                    
                     GoRouter.of(context).go('/dashboard');
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () {
                  GoRouter.of(context).go('/search');
                    
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.favorite),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () {
                    GoRouter.of(context).go('/favorites');
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () {
                    GoRouter.of(context).go('/profile');
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
abstract class SkillWaveRouter {
  static const initial = '/';
  static const dashboard = '/dashboard';
  static const profile = '/profile';
  static const update_profile = '/update_profile';
  static const search = '/search';
  static const favorites = '/favorites';
}
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:myapp/feature/course/screens/dashboard_screen.dart';
import 'package:myapp/feature/favorite/favorite_screen.dart';
import 'package:myapp/feature/profile/profile.dart';
import 'package:myapp/feature/search/search_scree.dart';
import 'package:myapp/router/domain/model_router.dart';

final router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: SkillWaveRouter.initial,
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: SkillWaveRouter.initial,
      builder: (context, state) => const DashboardScreen(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: SkillWaveRouter.favorites,
      builder: (context, state) => const FavoritesScreen(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: SkillWaveRouter.search,
      builder: (context, state) => const SearchScreen(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: SkillWaveRouter.profile,
      builder: (context, state) => ProfileScreen(),
    ),
  ],
);

══╡╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

js_primitives.dart:28 The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:

js_primitives.dart:28 Assertion failed:

js_primitives.dart:28 file:///home/user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/go_router-13.2.4/lib/src/router.dart:507:12

js_primitives.dart:28 inherited != null

js_primitives.dart:28 "No GoRouter found in context"

js_primitives.dart:28

js_primitives.dart:28 When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

js_primitives.dart:28 dart-sdk/lib/\_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 296:3       throw\_

js_primitives.dart:28 dart-sdk/lib/\_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 29:3        assertFailed

js_primitives.dart:28 packages/go_router/src/route_data.dart.js 3466:38                                 of

js_primitives.dart:28 packages/myapp/feature/bottom_bar/bottom_bar.dart.js 346:39                       \<fn\>

js_primitives.dart:28 packages/flutter/src/material/time.dart.js 74568:35                               handleTap

js_primitives.dart:28 packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart.js 325:18                           invokeCallback

js_primitives.dart:28 packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart.js 445:20                                  handleTapUp

js_primitives.dart:28 packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart.js 240:12                                  \[\_checkUp\]

js_primitives.dart:28 packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart.js 187:23                                  handlePrimaryPointer

js_primitives.dart:28 packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart.js 576:16                           handleEvent

js_primitives.dart:28 packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart.js 106:9                        \[\_dispatch\]

js_primitives.dart:28 packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart.js 132:26                       \<fn\>

js_primitives.dart:28 dart-sdk/lib/\_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/linked_hash_map.dart 21:7           forEach

js_primitives.dart:28 packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart.js 130:29                       \[\_dispatchEventToRoutes\]

js_primitives.dart:28 packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart.js 125:37                       route

js_primitives.dart:28 packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.js 444:26                              handleEvent

js_primitives.dart:28 packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.js 432:24                              dispatchEvent

js_primitives.dart:28 packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_state.dart.js 102392:13                       dispatchEvent

js_primitives.dart:28 packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.js 405:14                              \[\_handlePointerEventImmediately\]

js_primitives.dart:28 packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.js 376:43                              handlePointerEvent

js_primitives.dart:28 packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.js 365:14                              \[\_flushPointerEventQueue\]

js_primitives.dart:28 packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.js 340:40                              \[\_handlePointerDataPacket\]

js_primitives.dart:28 lib/\_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 1419:5                                invoke1

js_primitives.dart:28 lib/\_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 333:5                                 invokeOnPointerDataPacket

js_primitives.dart:28 lib/\_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 398:30                                    \[\_sendToFramework\]

js_primitives.dart:28 lib/\_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 224:7                                     onPointerData

js_primitives.dart:28 lib/\_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 1001:20                                   \<fn\>

js_primitives.dart:28 lib/\_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 930:7                                     \<fn\>

js_primitives.dart:28 lib/\_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 531:9                                     loggedHandler

js_primitives.dart:28 dart-sdk/lib/\_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 426:37  \_checkAndCall

js_primitives.dart:28 dart-sdk/lib/\_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 431:39  dcall

js_primitives.dart:28

js_primitives.dart:28 Handler: "onTap"

js_primitives.dart:28 Recognizer:

js_primitives.dart:28   TapGestureRecognizer#bc7c3

js_primitives.dart:28 ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

js_primitives.dart:28 Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///home/user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/go_router-13.2.4/lib/src/router.dart:507:12


Can you make sure of using go_router on MaterialApp.

Gorouter can not find the context so here you can simply declare GlobalKey key to the Gorouter and use that key's context to navigate in you app this will work.
